Scrollbar in HTML textarea is not scrolling automatically when the data is added via speech to text dictation software
I am using a text area in HTML. User of our application using speech to text software and it will put the that converted text to text area.
After 3 lines scrollbar comes showing but if user keeps dictating with speech the scrollbar is not scrolling automatically, so user does not know if the data is added or not. Although the data is added. But user wants it in real time, so scroll should work.
Please help me if someone came across this problem.

It seems this speech to text software isn't simulating keyboard input correctly. There's not much more to say: There's no code example in your question and we don't know what speech to text software is being used. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

@KIKOSoftware Actually there is no any separate code related to this. It is a simple HTML textarea and user keeps cursor on it and start saying something. So converted text from speech is start showing on textarea in real time. Software for dictation is DMO(Dragon Medical One)

It's probably time to contact NUANCE support.
